# how does one hide a contact to appear in 'active' on Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, chat

A particular contact when active, appears in my Active list in Facebook Messenger android app even though I have turned off chat for them on facebook.com website. How do I hide that person on the Messenger app?

Comment: I think that the question might be more suitable on [android.se] since eventually you're talking about a misbehavior in the app.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook just won't allow you to do it, as long as you open any Facebook app or website you will be "Active Now".
There is a new option in recent Messenger's update called "Availability"
[image]

Facebook claims it will prevent you from being shown in the  Active list, BUT  if you open a conversation with that person they can see your last activev time.

Comment: It works on the facebook.com chat; I can hide some people from appearing in my facebook chat by turning off chat for them. I was looking for a similar option on the Messenger app